# Ansible hosts to be set to a substring of a passed variable

Tags: ansible

I have a play like this:

```
- name: Perform an action on a Runtime
  hosts: all
  roles:
  - role: mule_action_on_Runtime
```

A variable at invocation (`--extra-vars 'mule_runtime=MuleS01-3.7.3-Testing'`) has a prefix of the host needed (`MuleS01`). I want to set hosts: MuleS01.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your pattern is always `PartIWant-PartIDonCareAbout-AnotherPartAfterOtherDash` you could use the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) method of Python, then get the first item of the list via the Jinja filter [`first`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#first).

Here is full working playbook as example:

```yaml
- hosts: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mule_runtime.split('-') | first }}"
```

This yield the recap:

```
play.yml --extra-vars 'mule_runtime=MuleS01-3.7.3-Testing'


PLAY [local] *******************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "msg": "MuleS01"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
local                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Based on on your answer I used:
`- name: Perform an action on a Runtime
  hosts: "{{ mule_runtime.split('-') | first }}"
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
  - role: mule_action`
And it work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

With the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
MuleS01
MuleS02
MuleS03
```

this playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Set {{ mule_runtime }}
      when: mule_runtime.split('-').0 == inventory_hostname
```

gives

```yaml
skipping: [MuleS02]
ok: [MuleS01] => {
    "msg": "Set MuleS01-3.7.3-Testing"
}
skipping: [MuleS03]
```